# IBM Worklight Adapters read-only and transactional access modes means?

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I was going through Worklight documentation and came across the topic [*Benefits of IBM Worklight adapters*](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_overview_of_ibm_worklight_adap.html); Adapters provide various benefits, one of them per the documentation is:

> Read-only and Transactional Capabilities: IBM Worklight adapters support read-only and transactional access modes to back-end
>   systems.

What is the meaning of `read-only` and `Transactional` modes? and is there any specific configuration to enable this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to "enable" per-se. This is just the nature of [using SQL adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf).

This is nothing unique to Worklight.

- See [this definition for "Database transaction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)
- Read-only means just that IMO: A database that can be opened (=used for) only for read access.

Comment: Thanks Idan for your inputs